# Code::Blocks doesn't show all code completion

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I write a function, variable etc. matches are displayed very strange (I wrote "bass_**l**", but it still shows matches what begin with "bass_**i**"). And I can't see matches below "BASS_INPUT_TYPE_SPEAKER" just because they go under my screen. 
Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can try to switch IDE (e.g. clion)

Comment: Is your question "how to make Code::Blocks completion hints case sensitive"? If not, then I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Do you *have* a symbol starting with `bass_l`?

Comment: C::B code completion  is simply not very good, I'm afraid.

Comment: Code completion does not refresh, when I write another letter